# how to convert xml response to class object in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Hi i am going for the xml response to convert as a class object in c#.i have get the xml from the sql side and call the one utility and get the xml and go for the convert in class object but with my code not return null in the class. any one know where is my problem then please let me know.

Here is my xml data :

```
<Users>
      <User>
            <UserId>1</UserId>
            <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
            <UserName>abc</UserName>
            <ProfileImage>20160816105401206.jpeg</ProfileImage>
            <Name>abc</Name>

            <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4608</FeedId>
            <Description>Test</Description>
            <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 2</Description>
            <Interest>Read</Interest>    
      </User>
       <User>
            <UserId>2</UserId>
            <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>
            <UserName>xyz</UserName>
            <ProfileImage>20160816105401207.jpeg</ProfileImage>
            <Name>xyz</Name>

            <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4610</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 3</Description>
            <Interest>swim</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4610</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 3</Description>
            <Interest>drive</Interest>    
      </User>
 </Users>
```

this is my class in c#:

```
        [XmlRoot]
    public class Users
    {
        [XmlRoot]
        public class User
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public int UserId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string ProfileImage { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public int FeedId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string Interest { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public int InterestId { get; set; }              

        }

        [XmlArray("UserList")]
        [XmlArrayItem("User")]
        public User[] ListUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my method in c#:

```
    public string xmldata()
    {           
        Users obju = new Users();

            string xml = "";
            DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Settings.ConnectionString(), "Getxml",1,10);
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    xml += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"].ToString();
                }
            }

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
            Users result;

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (Users)serializer.Deserialize(reader);// here i am not getting xml to in class 
            }                                               
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your xml in invalid. user </Users> replace of </users>

Comment: more specifically, the root node is terminated incorrectly; should be `</Users>`, not `</users>`. XML is case-sensitive

Comment: no it's valid xml

Comment: @coderwill well, it is valid now that you've edited it :)

Comment: modify your xml and try again

Comment: i will change my xml now it's correct you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<UserList>` that wraps them, so this isn't an xml-array. Instead, use:

```
[XmlElement("User")]
public User[] ListUsers { get; set; }
```

or better: `List<User>` instead of `User[]`; personally I'd have:

```
[XmlElement("User")]
public List<User> Users {get; } = new List<User>();
```

(but that also requires that you renaming the root type to something else)

On `User`, it isn't a root, so `[XmlRoot]` is redundant; and `[XmlElement]` is the default and assumed automatically, so you can remove all of the `[XmlElement]` from `User` too.

To show it all working just fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Users
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int FeedId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Interest { get; set; }
        public int InterestId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlElement("User")]
    public User[] ListUsers { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var obj = (Users)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ListUsers.Length); // 2
        }
    }



    const string xml = @"<Users>
      <User>
            <UserId>1</UserId>
            <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
            <UserName>abc</UserName>
            <ProfileImage>20160816105401206.jpeg</ProfileImage>
            <Name>abc</Name>

            <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4608</FeedId>
            <Description>Test</Description>
            <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 2</Description>
            <Interest>Read</Interest>    
      </User>
       <User>
            <UserId>2</UserId>
            <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>
            <UserName>xyz</UserName>
            <ProfileImage>20160816105401207.jpeg</ProfileImage>
            <Name>xyz</Name>

            <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4610</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 3</Description>
            <Interest>swim</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4610</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 3</Description>
            <Interest>drive</Interest>    
      </User>
 </Users>";

}
```

Comment: mean this line is not here write?

Comment: can you please give me one post as a answer please

Comment: @coderwill yes, the line that I'm explicitly calling out as incorrect: yes, I'm saying that it is incorrect; as for " give me one post as a answer" - I have no clue what you mean there; I *have* posted an answer...

Comment: Hello Marc Gravell i have try your solution and xml to getting data in object but i am getting always feedid is 0 so any idea?

Comment: may be in xml <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4608</FeedId>
            <Description>Test</Description>
            <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 2</Description>
            <Interest>Read</Interest>  this portion it's a repeat so here how can manage this

Comment: @coderwill feedid works just fine here - I get 4608 and 4610 by running the code in my answer. If you're getting something different, then that difference is due to some difference between your code and mine.

Comment: for userid 1 are you getting both feedid in one object?

Comment: @coderwill No; to see what I'm seeing, add `Console.WriteLine(obj.ListUsers[0].FeedId);` and `Console.WriteLine(obj.ListUsers[1].FeedId);` after the line `Console.WriteLine(obj.ListUsers.Length); // 2` in my code. It works perfectly

Comment: i want to both feedid and data for userid 1 in one object

Comment: @coderwill "i want to both feedid and data for userid 1 in one object" cannot parse; please rephrase so I can understand what you mean. Be very specific.

Comment: i mean first time for userid 1 is come ok then 1st object it's create now in 1st object i want to get this is data  <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4608</FeedId>
            <Description>Test</Description>
            <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 2</Description>
            <Interest>Read</Interest>     also

Comment: @coderwill that is a **completely different** xml structure! there is no easy way to make `XmlSerializer` split that into objects, since the xml itself is not itemized. You'd have to use a *completely* different approach for that.

Comment: have you not idea how can do that have you idea then please let me know i am suffering for that

Comment: @coderwill I strongly suggest that you post the *actual* xml into the question, including the xml root. The exact structure of the xml **matters a lot**, and you keep changing it.

Comment: i know i am post the for the xml to convert class object so it's done but i am suffering problem with is so i am asking to you. are you getting confuse then  i am rely so sry for that

Comment: @coderwill the xml that is in the question is **completely different** to the xml you have posted in the comments. The difference **really matters**. I can certainly help you with either, but if I can't see the actual xml that is problematic, I can only guess

Answer (score 1):

User this class for serialization and destabilization

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="User")]
    public class User {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ProfileImage")]
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="InterestId")]
        public List<string> InterestId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FeedId")]
        public List<string> FeedId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Description")]
        public List<string> Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Interest")]
        public List<string> Interest { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Users")]
    public class Users {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="User")]
        public List<User> User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: the *only* attribute there that actually matters is the one on the list; *all* of the rest are unnecessary

Comment: in my xml <InterestId>8</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4608</FeedId>
            <Description>Test</Description>
            <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>    

            <InterestId>12</InterestId>
            <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
            <Description>Test 2</Description>
            <Interest>Read</Interest>  this portion it's repeat so how can manage this with your solution it's getting only 1 and feedid is 0 getting

Comment: @coderwill that is a **completely different** xml structure! there is no easy way to make `XmlSerializer` split that into objects, since the xml itself is not itemized

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 2 completely different xml structures in play here; one neatly itemized in the question, and one that is *not* itemized - in the comments. By non-itemized, I mean that individual elements bleed into each-other without a wrapper per object, like so:

```
<InterestId>8</InterestId>
<FeedId>4608</FeedId>
<Description>Test</Description>
<Interest>Cricekt</Interest>
<InterestId>12</InterestId>
<FeedId>4609</FeedId>
<Description>Test 2</Description>
<Interest>Read</Interest>
```

The first is a good fit for `XmlSerializer`, which excels are pulling apart itemized xml, but really can't help much for non-itemized. To read such a model tends to be more manual. I would probably:

- identify the first element per batch
- read until the next of those elements
- resolve the other child elements from between the two

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var el = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root;

        var interests = from intIdEl in el.Elements("InterestId")
                        let children = intIdEl.ElementsAfterSelf().TakeWhile(
                            x => x.Name != "InterestId")
                        let feedIdEl = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "FeedId")
                        let descIdEl = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Description")
                        let intEl = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Interest")
                        select new
                        {
                            InterestId = (int?)intIdEl,
                            FeedId = (int?)feedIdEl,
                            Description = (string)descIdEl,
                            Interest = (string)intEl
                        };

        foreach(var obj in interests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
              $"{obj.InterestId}, {obj.FeedId}, {obj.Description}, {obj.Interest}");
        }
    }
    const string xml = @"<Users>
<InterestId>8</InterestId><FeedId>4608</FeedId>
<Description>Test</Description> <Interest>Cricekt</Interest>
<InterestId>12</InterestId> <FeedId>4609</FeedId>
<Description>Test 2</Description> <Interest>Read</Interest>
</Users>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helping and now i am change the my xml so now my problem it's gone now. i have add new Root as a <Feed></Feed>

Comment: Hello Marc Gravell can you please help me one? i am getting error like this '"There is an error in XML document (901, 424).' can you please let me know this error is why come or what meaning of this error. i am run my utility then page index 1 give and par page 20 data i am pass that time its' run then come page index 2 then go for the deserialize that time got this error.